# What is a VAD package in virtuoso?

Tags: virtuoso

I googled quite a lot but beside installation instructions I could not find an answer to my simple question:

What is a Virtuoso Application distribution (VAD) package and what it is useful for?

I am mostly interested in dbpedia: having already loaded dbpedia data, what is the added value of installing `dbpedia_dav.vad` ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Product documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/databaseadmsrv.html#vaddistr) is a useful resource to start with --

> **6.1.4. VAD - Virtuoso Application Distribution**
>
> VAD provides a package distribution framework for installation, management, dependency checking, and un-installation of Virtuoso applications. A VAD package contains all required Virtuoso components, which would constitute an application or hosted solution, within a single distributable file. A VAD package cannot contain any system parts independent of Virtuoso, thus excludes operating system executables, shared objects, installers, and settings.

To your specific --

The DBpedia VAD includes various things, like the "[green page](http://dbpedia.org/page/Virtuoso_Universal_Server)" template, which are not part of the DBpedia data set nor the base Virtuoso install.

For the future --

DBpedia-specific questions are often better raised to the [DBpedia Discussion list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion).

Virtuoso-specific questions are often better raised in Virtuoso-specific arenas, such as the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [public OpenLink Support Forums](https://community.openlinksw.com/), or a [confidential OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

*ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of Virtuoso, supporter of DBpedia.*